# Line after blockquote in spoiler not a spoiler?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, spoilers

When putting a blockquote in a spoiler, the line(s) after the blockquote are not hidden; this does not seem to be the behaviour I would expect? Hovering over the spoiler reveals the hidden text as expected.

Markdown:

```
>! Line 1
>! <blockquote>Line 2</blockquote>
>! Line 3
```

Result (rendered):

> Line 1
>
> > Line 2
>
> Line 3

Result (in picture form):
[image]

I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox 76.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't supported. Everything inside a spoiler block is treated as a single paragraph of text. If you want to use block elements inside of it, then you'll have to be explicit about making *everything* a block element, like this:

```
>! <p>Line 1</p>
>! <blockquote>Line 2</blockquote>
>! <p>Line 3</p>
```

> Line 1
>
> > Line 2
>
> Line 3

While doing this makes all of the text disappear as intended by the spoiler around it, it does still have the negative side-effect of putting empty paragraph at the beginning and end of the spoiler which make the block much larger, because again this is not supported.