# Are nested spoiler tags possible in a post?

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

As we all know, there is the option to have a quote format within a quote format, like so:

> Some text
>
> > Some other text

Is there a way to have a spoiler tag within a spoiler tag?

Currently, using the same logic as the quote format, I get:

> Some text
> >! Some other text

Comment: This is most probably not possible... Related: [Line after blockquote in spoiler not a spoiler?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347955/986753)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not possible. Spoilers [do not support block-level Markdown processing](/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well), only inline (and manual HTML, though not very well). Since it's not possible to manually create spoilers with allowable HTML, that means you cannot possibly insert a spoiler within another spoiler.